# fopen/fwrite path above public_html issue

Tags: php, bash, debian

I'm testing php scripts on my web server.
I'm using a basic fopen / fwrite to write data to file.
The following scripts works perfectly in public_html/ but fails to work in folders above "I'm trying in /test/"

centOS with WHM/cPanel, latest.

```
<?php
$fp = fopen('lidn.sh', 'w');
fwrite($fp, 'Cats chase mice');
fclose($fp);
?>
```

This works fine. However:

```
<?php
$fp = fopen('/test/lidn.sh', 'w');
fwrite($fp, 'Cats chase mice');
fclose($fp);
?>
```

doesn't write anything to file.

I need php to output data to a ".sh" file, so having it inside public_html would, I think, be a gigantic security flaw.

The goal is to securely output data to a ".sh" via PHP

Answer (score 0):

You should check the test folder permissions.

Comment: I just chmod 750 test/.

Did not fix.

Comment: @EdwardOak Which owner and group? Remember that webbrowser probably do no use your user permission. In PHP you can define where it can write (good practice is to limit file access to just a very limited part of filesystem). In any case writting a `.sh` is always a security problem. Refactor.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Thanks, I will try to output to a .json file instead. I'm pretty sure it's possible to fetch json values/variables from bash script.

If you want to add your comment as an Answer, I will select it as Best Answer and close the 'case'.